# can not insert checkbox value into mysql database using comma

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have searched a lot for a way to insert checkbox values into a mysql database with the values separated by comma. But none of my attempts have so far worked, below you can see my code:

The HTML code:

> ```
>  <form role="form"  action="zone_detail1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <label for="sc">Zone Name for Identification</label>
>                     <input required type="text" class="form-control"  name="txtzonename" placeholder="Enter Name">
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <label for="sc">Day(s) for Zone</label><br>
>                     <input type="checkbox" name="txtday" value="Monday" />Monday
>                     <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday" value="Tuesday"  />Tuesday
>                     <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday" value="Wednesday"  />Wednesday
>                     <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday" value="Thrusday"  />Thrusday
>                     <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday" value="Friday"  />Friday
>                     <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday" value="Saturday"  />Saturday
>                     <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday" value="Sunday"  />Sunday
>                     </div> 
>                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn_submit" value="Submit"/>
>             </form>
> ```

```
  <?php
 include("db.php");
 session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {   
    //retrieve our data from POST
    $zone_name = $_POST['txtzonename'];
    $zone_days = @mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['txtday'])); 
    $sql="Insert into `zone` (zone_name , zone_turn) values('$zone_name',     '$zone_days')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result){
    $msg="Data Inserted Successfully..!!";
     $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;   
    header("location:zone_detail.php");
     }
    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }     
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try like this $zone_days = join(',',$_POST['txtday']);

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: What is the result of your code? Do you have error then please you post your error?

Comment: @Plum Why should he use `join` instead of `implode`? `implode` and `explode` are the normal PHP names for these functions.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['txtday'])` show?

Comment: its doesn't show any error. But it can not insert into database

Comment: can we see your html of checkbox?

Comment: what kind of field is "zone_turn"?

Comment: Can you please describe your zone table. it might help!

Comment: I had edit my question kindly refer it

Comment: you should use name="txtday[]" for the name @NidhiShah

Comment: Thank you so much its work perfectly. @John Roca.

Comment: @NidhiShah I will post my answer and you can mark it as correct. Glad I could help. Best! John

Answer (score 0):

You should specify

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtday[]" value="Monday">Monday<br>
```

as array.

Add `[]` to all names txtday and work at php with this like an `array`.

After it, you can `INSERT` values at different columns at db, or use `implode` and save values into one column.

**Don't forget to replace `mysql` with `mysqli`.** Also keep in mind that mysql_* functions are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#13944958) for more information.

**HTML Code**

```
<form role="form"  action="zone_detail1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sc">Zone Name for Identification</label>
        <input required type="text" class="form-control"  name="txtzonename" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sc">Day(s) for Zone</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="txtday[]" value="Monday" />Monday
        <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Tuesday"  />Tuesday
        <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Wednesday"  />Wednesday
        <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Thrusday"  />Thrusday
        <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Friday"  />Friday
        <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Saturday"  />Saturday
        <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Sunday"  />Sunday
    </div> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn_submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
 include("db.php");
 session_start();

 if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {   
    //retrieve our data from POST
    $zone_name = $_POST['txtzonename'];
    $zone_days = implode(',', $_POST['txtday']);
    $sql="Insert into `zone` (zone_name , zone_turn) values('".$zone_name."',     '".$zone_days."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result){
    $msg="Data Inserted Successfully..!!";
     $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;   
    header("location:zone_detail.php");
     }
    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }     
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *name="txtday[]"* in your mark up.

**In your input element you should specify:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtday[]" value="Monday" />
```

**Update your mark up like this:**

```
 <form role="form"  action="zone_detail1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sc">Zone Name for Identification</label>
                <input required type="text" class="form-control"  name="txtzonename" placeholder="Enter Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sc">Day(s) for Zone</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="txtday[]" value="Monday" />Monday
                <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Tuesday"  />Tuesday
                <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Wednesday"  />Wednesday
                <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Thrusday"  />Thrusday
                <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Friday"  />Friday
                <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[]" value="Saturday"  />Saturday
                <input type="checkbox"  name="txtday[] value="Sunday"  />Sunday
                </div> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn_submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

You can see this [tutorial](http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/php-multiple-checkbox-array-handling/) for your reference.